# devcontainer in vscode fails with error: Only one instance of "host" network is allowed

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have a project that used to work. (famous last words right?)
Just tried to open it up in a dev container but it fails with the error

> [+] Running 1/0  ✘ Network integrationtests_integration-test-network
> Error                0.0s failed to create network
> integrationtests_integration-test-network: Error respon se from
> daemon: only one instance of "host" network is allowed

Here's what the docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  integration-tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /workspaces/IntegrationTests
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
      - 7071:7071
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:10.222.22.222
    volumes:
      - ../IntegrationTests/Tests:/workspaces/IntegrationTests
    networks:
      - integration-test-network

networks:
  integration-test-network:
    driver: host
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/microsoftgraph/powershell:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim 
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
WORKDIR /workspaces/IntegrationTests
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

**Docker networks:**

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\widgets\IntegrationTests> docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
asdfasdfasdfas bridge    bridge    local
123123asfffff  host      host      local
123445555fasdf none      null      local
```

Docker containers:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\widgets\IntegrationTests> docker ps        
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\widgets\IntegrationTests>
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried to replace this in the docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  - integration-test-network
```

with this:

```
network_mode:
  - host
```

And I removed the networks section.  But I get the error:

```
 "services.integration-tests.network_mode must be a string"
```

Currently googling what the correct syntax is but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For most applications, you shouldn't need any `networks:` or `network_mode:` settings at all.  Does deleting these help?